# Legend issue and display custom message in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend

I am having trouble adding a chart legend to my d3js chart. Here is my current whole approach to creating donut chart:

```
//data set
    var data = { "rows":[
                             {"STATUS":"Active", "NUMBER_OF_POLICIES":246}, 
                             {"STATUS":"Not", "NUMBER_OF_POLICIES":140}
                            ]   
                        };
                width =450;
                height = 450;
                radius = Math.min(width,height)/2;
                var color = d3.scale.category20c();
                var arc = d3.svg.arc()  
                         .outerRadius(radius -90)
                         .innerRadius(radius - 10);
                var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()  
                        .outerRadius(radius+50)
                        var svg = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
                        .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height)+' '+Math.min(width,height))
                        .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + ")");                       
                div = d3.select("body")
                        .append("div") 
                        .attr("class", "tooltip");
                var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                          .sort(null)
                          .value(function(d){return d.NUMBER_OF_POLICIES;});
                var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                        .data(pie(data.rows))
                        .enter()
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("class","arc")
                         .on("mousemove",function(d){
                            var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
                            div.style("display","none");
                            div
                            .html("STATUS:"+d.data.STATUS+"</br>"+"NUMBER_OF_POLICIES:"+d.data.NUMBER_OF_POLICIES)
                            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+12) + "px")
                            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10) + "px")
                            .style("opacity", 1)
                            .style("display","block");
                        })
                        .on("mouseout",function(){div.html(" ").style("display","none");})
                        .on("click",function(d){
                            if(d3.select(this).attr("transform") == null){
                            d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate(42,0)");
                            }else{
                                d3.select(this).attr("transform",null);
                            }
                        });
                        g.append("path")
                        .attr("d",arc)
                        .style("fill",function(d){return color(d.data.STATUS);});
                        // add legend   
                var legend = svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "legend")
                      .attr("x", width - 65)
                      .attr("y", 25)
                      .attr("height", 100)
                      .attr("width", 100);
                    legend.selectAll('g').data(data)
                      .enter()
                      .append('g')
                      .each(function(d, i) {
                        var g = d3.select(this);
                        g.append("rect")
                          .attr("x", width - 65)
                          .attr("y", i*25)
                          .attr("width", 10)
                          .attr("height", 10)
                          .style("fill", color);
                        g.append("text")
                          .attr("x", width - 50)
                          .attr("y", i * 25 + 8)
                          .attr("height",30)
                          .attr("width",100)
                          .style("fill", color)
                      .text(function(d) { return d });
                          });
```

Is anyone familiar with adding legends to charts able to provide the best way to do so?Here my data set was coming dynamically and stored into data variable as i have mentioned above in my code.Also is their possible to display one custom message if their is no data available in data variable then i want to display message like 'sorry no data found.'Is it possible to display custom message.Please guide me How i can do

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://zeroviscosity.com/d3-js-step-by-step/step-3-adding-a-legend)?

Comment: Hi Lars..Thanks for your quick response ..yes i have seen ..but i want to create the legend out side the donut chart instead of inside..bcoz my text will be more as data is coming dynamically through web api ..?Also inside legend making problem for creating responsive chart ..so i m looking approach to creating the legend out side the chart ..so plz help me what i m doing wrong in my code..

Comment: Any one having same issue what i m facing

Comment: @LarsKotthoff :Thanks a lot for your help i have solved my issue.

Comment: @sam140 How did you Solve Can Please Post the same as a Answer.It will be helpful for any other. As I am also struck with the Such Problem. Thanks